# Are game shows on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about *A League of Their Own* which, while technically being about TV, could be construed as off-topic. I just want to know if questions about game shows like ALOTO, The Price is Right etc. are on topic here.

Comment: I was confused by this question because there's a good American movie by the same name, lol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_League_of_Their_Own

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We don't get many questions about them, but yes, game/quiz shows are on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, yes they are on-topic.  However, be wary when posting questions because it could very easily fall into the trivial question trap.  Most game shows don't produce a lot of story points, and asking who did what in a game show just wouldn't be very interesting on this site.